# Can I use mailto: as support URL in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Can I use mailto: as my support URL in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can or can't, you'll have to put it through the review process to find out for sure. I do know that I've had a rejection for an invalid support URL (page wasn't available). I'd suggest just creating a web page with an email address or support form. That's what the user would expect.

Comment: ya i am going to go with this option instead of risking a rejection.